# How do I make layouts different for each device?

Tags: android

I have a land layout how do I get layout's different for each device so stuff looks better on the nexus 7 etc.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the doc links posted above. Basically you do it like this.

```
res/layout-land/main_activity.xml           # For phones
res/layout-sw600dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets
```

sw-600dp tells the system to load layouts from this folder for devices that have a smallest width dimension of 600dp (device independent pixels)